# 100% width divs not spanning entire width of the browser in webkit

Tags: css, webkit, width

I'm having a hard time with what I thought would be a dead simple issue.

I'm trying to create a div that spans 100% of the width of a browser window. The div is filled with several child divs that expand to fill that entire space with alternating colors like a football field. These divs would expand to fit the full width of a given space that has individual 1% stripes that fill that space fully.

This seems to work fine in Firefox, but in Safari (and Chrome) the calculation seems to be too strict, and leaves some extra leftover space on the right-most div.

Is there any way to avoid this leftover space? I've encountered the same issue in Safari and Chrome even when placing it in a fixed width div... there is always space left over on the right. I wonder if I'm just asking it to do too much math?

Here is the code I am using, with alternate versions dividing the space into divisions of 5% and divisions of 1%. Sorry, it's long and redundant code.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.clearfix {
    visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}    

#field {
    width: 100%;
    background: #009900;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 0;
}    

.singleyard {
    width: 1%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #009900;
}    

.fiveyards {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.alt {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.oneyard {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

-->
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="field">
  <div class="fiveyards">5</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">10</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">15</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">20</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">25</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">30</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">35</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">40</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">45</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">50</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">55</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">60</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">65</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">70</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">75</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">80</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">85</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">90</div>

  <div class="fiveyards">95</div>
  <div class="fiveyards alt">100</div>

</div>


<div id="field">
<!--below section is repeated 10 times -->
<div class="singleyard">1</div>
<div class="singleyard">2</div>
<div class="singleyard">3</div>
<div class="singleyard">4</div>
<div class="singleyard">5</div>
<div class="singleyard">6</div>
<div class="singleyard">7</div>
<div class="singleyard">8</div>
<div class="singleyard">9</div>
<div class="singleyard alt">10</div>
<!--end repeated section-->

</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are all your css styles commented out btw?

Comment: Ha. No idea why those comment tags were in there, but thanks for the catch. Unfortunately, removing them hasn't helped.

Comment: What is the final status of your development. Have you found an answer. I am facing similar issues.(refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089419/full-width-of-the-mobile-not-possible-phonegap-requirejs-jquery)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, this is what I discovered: somewhere in your CSS you have another div that has a width of 100% and ALSO has padding.  Since the padding value is added to the width, the value of that div becomes greater than 100%.  The solution is to make sure not to use padding on any div that is set to 100% width.  If you need padding, try adding the padding to the element inside the div instead.

Comment: Bingo! Similarly, `body { margin: 0; }` may allow elements to be really and truly `width: 100%;` in some old browsers (Android 4.1). Alternative may be to give [intervening divs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867800/673991) `position: relative;`

Answer (score 4):

Only thing I can think of is to add:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just to make sure safari knows the parent container of field is also 100%;

Another thing to try is to add:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

That should force a side scrollbar, even if it's grayed out. I wonder if some webkit rendering temporarily flashes a scrollbar, but fails to give the space back. Any of that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately the issue persists. I think I've narrowed it down to Safari and Chrome rounding %-based widths to 1/2 of a percent (and no further) which results in the left over space unless the total width is "pixel-perfect". Maybe I can think up a way to trick the browser into calculating it correctly, but the solution still eludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed mine by

```
body
{
background-color:#dddddd;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by using display: table-cell

```
#field {
    width: 100%;
    background: #009900;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}    

.singleyard {
    width: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #090;
    display: table-cell;
}

.fiveyards {
    width: 5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience on a similar issue. When your code will not stretch the entire way on the mobile device (but will on the desktop), fixing it is a matter of finding some element that is pushing the boundary invisibly. There should be some item that is breaking out of its boundary - for me it was a logo image that was sticking about 20px outside the header div. You can find this by giving everything a border or by eliminating one thing at a time. Once you have found it, you can move it or remove it in order to allow things to stretch the full way again.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed mine by adding

```
html, body
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this wasn't answered. I was having the same issue. I added the following lines to my CSS class:

```
margin-right:-10px;
margin-left:-10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `min-width: 100%` seems to do the trick