# HTML List 5 Columns

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Why is following CSS-Code not filling up 100% of the screen? I've 5 columns with a width of 20% percent floating left.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            height: 42px;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: inline;
            height: 42px;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
            display: inline;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            height: 42px;
            line-height: 42px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            width: auto;
        }
        a:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #FFF;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Clients</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Articles</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

There is always a red area on the right side, but 5*20% = 100% so that can't be. What is wrong?

Kind regards,
PP

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vs5s5/

Comment: can you show your error page here?

Comment: A lot has been written concerning this, but no real solution was found: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/ and http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see this issue in Safari. It only occurs sometimes when resizing the browser. It seems to be a rounding problem in WebKit browsers. I found this similar qwuestion "[100% width divs not spanning entire width of the browser in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659359/1456376)" with this comment:

> Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately the issue persists. I think I've narrowed it down to Safari and Chrome rounding %-based widths to 1/2 of a percent (and no further) which results in the left over space unless the total width is "pixel-perfect". Maybe I can think up a way to trick the browser into calculating it correctly, but the solution still eludes me at the moment.

Maybe you can use `display: table-cell` on the `<li>`-tags to avoid this problem, as this should force the browser to always use the 100% width.

**Example HTML**

```
​<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Value 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Value 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Value 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Value 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Value 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Example CSS**

```
​ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: green;
}

li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

**Try before buy**

http://jsfiddle.net/Fsjns/

Comment: Why not? I updated my answer with an example, how it could work.

Comment: OK, thank you very much it works now...I forgot to delete the "float: left;".

Answer (score 0):

Resolution 1024*(20/100) = 204.8 px

Resolution 1366*(20/100) = 207.2 px

I think the screen cannot display less than a pixel

Comment: That's true, of course, but other browser engines round those things nicely.