# How to make div's percentage width relative to parent div and not viewport

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

[Here is the HTML I am working with](http://jsfiddle.net/XXm6V/).

```html
<div id="outer" style="min-width: 2000px; min-height: 1000px; background: #3e3e3e;">
  <div id="inner" style="left: 1%; top: 45px; width: 50%; height: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
    <div style="background: #efffef; position: absolute; height: 400px; right: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to happen is for the inner div to occupy 50% of the space given to its parent div(outer). Instead, is is getting 50% of the space available to the viewport, which means that as the browser/viewport shrinks in size, so does it.

Given that the outer div has `min-width` of `2000px`, I would expect the inner div to be at least `1000px` wide.

Comment: the inner div is `position: absolute`, which means it's essentially removed from the normal document flow, and is no longer (for size/position calculations) a child of #outer. You might want to try `position: relative`

Comment: @MarcB It is no longer in the flow of its parent, but your comment about no being a child of #outer is misleading. The more accurate description is that it uses the first parent/ancestor that is absolutely or relatively positioned for size/position calculations

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Specifying a non-static position, e.g., `position: absolute/relative` on a node means that it will be used as the reference for absolutely positioned elements within it http://jsfiddle.net/E5eEk/1/

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Positioning_contexts

> We can change the positioning context — which element the absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to. This is done by setting positioning on one of the element's ancestors.

```css
#outer {
  min-width: 2000px; 
  min-height: 1000px; 
  background: #3e3e3e; 
  position:relative
}

#inner {
  left: 1%; 
  top: 45px; 
  width: 50%; 
  height: auto; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#inner-inner {
  background: #efffef;
  position: absolute; 
  height: 400px; 
  right: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="inner-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was here for this explanation! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that about `position: relative` and `absolute`. +1!

Answer (score 19):

Use position: relative on the parent element.

Also note that had you not added any position attributes to any of the divs you wouldn't have seen this behavior. Juan explains further.

Comment: I did upvote this answer, just didn't think it provided enough of an explanation. Teach them to fish

Comment: I'm not poking fun at you specifically. It's just a humorous observation.