# Absolute positioning

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

I'm trying to understand the basics of positioning, and I came across this example on the internet that displays specific properties. Essentially, they created two boxes with CSS:

```
#box_1 { 
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 { 
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #44accf;
}
```

Because absolute positioning places the container in relation to its first parent element, shouldn't the second box be placed at the top of the browser, and then left 100 pixels? With this definition of absolute positioning, shouldn't the two boxes overlap? Instead, the second box ends up below the first box. I thought that absolute positioning removes an object from the normal flow of a page? Can anyone explain this to me?

Here's what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/WScGM/

Comment: SVSchmidt's answer is a pretty good summary. One thing I'd like to clarify from your question though is this. Absolutely positioned elements are NOT positioned according to their first parent element. They are positioned according to the closest ancestor that is `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. When you haven't specified any other relative or absolute items, then this ends up being the `body`, not the item's parent.

Comment: @AndyM That's correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[W3C says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position):

> Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow.

and

> The box's position ... is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties

In your example, you haven't defined a value for "top" or "bottom" (the vertical position). The initial value of top/left/right/bottom is "auto". So I believe this is the reason the element keeps its vertical position. The actually calculated styling would look like:

```
position:absolute;
left:100px;
right:auto;
top:auto;
bottom:auto;
```

That means it behaves like if it was in the normal flow but it's 100px more right.
But if you put a third box without absolute positioning in the document, the absolute one will overlap it.

To position it 100px from the left upper edge, add

```
top:0;
```

to your CSS.

Comment: You are correct. When `top` isn't specified, it is treated as `auto`. `top:auto` will cause the item to be placed vertically in the spot that it would appear if it was positioned statically.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute positioning** is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it.

You can use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning.

If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of elements on the page.

An element with this type of positioning is not affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute positioning.

Now comes your question: **shouldn't the second box be placed at the top of the browser, and then left 100 pixels?** **With this definition of absolute positioning, shouldn't the two boxes overlap?**

yes of course, by the definition of absolute positioning, the two boxes should overlap, if both are in absolute positioning.

This is because by default one of them is in in static positioning.

Now I have made both in `absolute` position as following:

```
#box_1 { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ee3e64;
    position:absolute;
}
#box_2 { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #44accf;
}
```

and so, now they are overlapping.See here:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/WScGM/8/)

Comment: I don't think that's the question. They don't overlap because the OP has not specified a top, so its top is whatever it would be if it were not absolute.

Comment: @JuanMendes check the difference what if you do not specify position:absolute in #box1 and what if you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "top:0" for the second box for overlapping.

Comment: So unless I add in a property that would remove the normal flow, position absolute does follow the normal flow of a doc?

Comment: Kind of. It will be positioned as though it is in the normal flow but it will have no effect on other elements. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WScGM/5/

Comment: This doesn't explain WHY you need to add `top:0;`

Comment: It does! Adding no value for "top" makes top = auto like SVSchmidt explained above me.

Comment: Exactly, SVSchmidt explained why top is needed. You said what to do (add top:0;) without explaining why.