# Make text in the middle of CSS shapes

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, css-shapes

```css
.myButton {
  float: right;
  border-top: 40px solid pink;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myButton">
  Submit
</div>
```

The above is my code. As you can see I want to design a shape like the image below but I want the word `Submit` to be in the center but it is pushed down.
Anyone know a solution?

[image]

Comment: You can put the text inside of a `div` and use `position:absolute;` to adjust where it sits inside of the div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766590/absolute-positioning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` background for this. Techique is based on setting fixed height and then applying `padding` equals `height` multiplied by `√2`:

```css
.my-button {
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 40px, pink 40px);
  padding-left: 56.5691px; /* 40 × √2 ≈ 56.5691 */
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Also you can achieve this via absolutely position pseudoelement:

```css
.my-button {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 0;
}

.my-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Move pseudoelement to the left to 100% of its width */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-top: 40px solid pink;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you have is that you're using a top border instead of a background so your text naturally won't look to be in the center of your shape. What you can do is use positioning to manually move your text up within the shape:

```css
.myButton {
  float: right;
  border-top: 40px solid pink;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myButton">
  <div class="inner">Submit</div>
</div>
```