# Javascript: create multiple elements into a `for` loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

In my project I'm trying to create, with DOM and JavaScript, a loop to create multiple elements, like this example:

```
for (i = 0; i < response.click.length; i++) 
{
    var divClick = createElement('div', 'divClick', 'divClk');
    divClick.setAttribute('style','top: '+response.click[i].ypos+';');
    divClick.setAttribute('style','left: '+response.click[i].xpos+';');
    divLogin.appendChild(divClick);
}
```

In practice I need to append at one main `div` a series of `div`s (little blue square - `divClick`) positioned using value parsing from  `ypos` and `xpos`, but with this code the result is just one square positioned at 0,0 coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
position: relative;
```

on your container div and

```
position: absolute;
```

on your child divs.

Comment: For more explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800