# How to overlap elements inside of a ng-repeat list - position: absolute?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

this is the html:

```
<div class = "container">
   <form ng-submit = "createSticky()">
      <input ng-model="formData.data" type="textarea" name="sticky_content" placeholder="add sticky text" required="true"/>
      <input ng-model="formData.end" type="text" name="time_end" placeholder="expiration time (sec)" required="true"/>
      <button type="submit" name="add_sticky" value="add a new stickie!">new sticky</button>
   </form>
   <div id = "stickies_list" class="row">
      <ul id = "stickies">
         <span class="sticky">
            <li ng-repeat="stickie in stickies" ng-click="match(stickie)">
               <button id="delete_checkbox" ng-click="deleteSticky(stickie.id)">X</button>
               <h3>{{stickie.data}}</h3>
               <div id="time_data">
               start: <h10><mydate>{{stickie.start | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</mydate></h10><br>
               stop: <h10><mydate>{{stickie.end | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</mydate></h10> 
               </div>
            </li>
         </span>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
sticky #time_data {
  postion:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Right now the time_data div appears after the rest of the info in the "sticky" span. So if stickies.data is really long, it gets pushed way down.

Instead, the desired behavior is to have the time_data div overlap with the rest of the information in the "sticky" class. so that they are independent of each other. I do not want the time_data to only start after the rest of the "sticky" class. That is why I am using position:absolute. I am modeling this after http://jsbin.com/fecego/1/edit which works perfectly. How can do whats in that jsbin in my code so that it overlaps as well?

Comment: There's got to be more CSS than what you're posting. It'd be much easier if you also provided a link to the (not-working) angular version. You should not have something with an ID inside of a `ng-repeat`, only one ID per page. In your example, the `meta` div is outside the `ul`, but in the angular version it's inside the `li` so your example doesn't say much about the problem

Comment: Also to make something positioned inside of a parent element, you have to give your parent `position: relative`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800 See http://jsbin.com/fitewewilibe/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're asking but if you want your `div` to overlap with the contents of the `li`, the li has to be `position:relative` or absolute and the `div` has to be inside of your `li` (your jsbin example didn't do that). Something like:

```
<span class="sticky">
  <ul>
    <li> list 
      <div class="meta"><p> I should be overlapping with the list, and I am!</p></div>
    </li>
    <li> is 
      <div class="meta"><p> I should be overlapping with the list, and I am!</p></div>
    </li>
    <li> very 
      <div class="meta"><p> I should be overlapping with the list, and I am!</p></div>
    </li>
    <li> long 
      <div class="meta"><p> I should be overlapping with the list, and I am!</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.sticky .meta { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.sticky li {
  position: relative
}
```

See [How to make div's percentage width relative to parent div and not viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800)