# Absolutely positioned div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a css animation, which makes a div go under another div. DIV 1 goes under DIV 2. If I make DIV 2 absolutely positioned, the page will break in pieces. But if I don't make the DIV 2 absolutely positioned, the DIV 1 will not go under it, buy stay at the top of the div.

You can check it out live [here](http://budapestflats.hu/single.php?id=3)

This is how it looks without making the right content absolutely positioned.

If you hover your mouse over the map, you will see the transition.

Any helpful solutions of getting rid of this? I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did your DIV 1 and DIV 2 have position:relative or something else??

Comment: No they don't have any now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is why it don't work, your parent div has to have position to child div position take effect.

```css
.div1, .div2{
position:relative;
}
.div3{
position:absolute;
}
```

Take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: This time I made the div absolutely positioned, and now the page didn't break into pieces, but it is not scrollable any more. But thanks for the answer I accept it. ( 8 min to accept )

Answer (score 2):

Make Div 2 be `position: relative` so that it stays in the flow. See [How to make div's percentage width relative to parent div and not viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800)

From that answer:

> Specifying `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` on a node means that it will be used as the reference for absolutely positioned elements within it http://jsfiddle.net/E5eEk/1/

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}

.info {
z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the `#content` to be the top layer add `z-index` with a higher value with the other div.

Take note, `z-index` doesn't work if you don't set your div `position:absolute` or `position: relative`

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```