# A div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I want to scale an inner div by a percentage of the height of an outer div, not by the percentage of the viewport. How do I go about doing that? Here's some dummy HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

.outer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.inner {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50px;
}
```

In this case, I would like the resulting height of the inner div to be 50px, instead of 800-ish px (half the height of my screen).

Comment: When I use the css provided, it does as you asked. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwafkgcs/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867800/1870760

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want it to do. Add a border to both divs and see for yourself.