# Position Absolute inside position absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple interactive HTML component, and have run into an issue I just cannot figure out.  I have a set of circles that use absolute positioning, and when you hover over them I want a text box to appear centered over the circle. They do not currently appear centered, despite my css code that should offset it through "top" and "left".

I have gone over the documentation for "top" and "left" and don't see why they do not seem to have any effect here.  If someone could explain why "top" and "left" seem to have no effect in this case that would be greatly appreciated.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/0qvep3ng/2

```css
#gear_of_coolness {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.coolness-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #ee7622;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
}

.coolness-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Replica-Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #3f4642;
}

.coolness-popup {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 125px;
  top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Replica-Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 79, 0.7);
  display: none;
}

.coolness-icon:hover>.coolness-popup {
  display: block;
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(-50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(14.6% - 50px);
  left: calc(85.3% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(3) {
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(4) {
  top: calc(85.3% - 50px);
  left: calc(85.3% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(5) {
  top: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(6) {
  top: calc(85.3% - 50px);
  left: calc(14.6% - 50px);
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(7) {
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: -50px;
}

.coolness-icon:nth-child(8) {
  top: calc(14.6% - 50px);
  left: calc(14.6% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<section id="home_intro">
  <div id="gear_of_coolness">
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 1 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 2 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 3 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 4 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 5 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 6 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 7 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="coolness-icon">
      <div class="coolness-title">Circle 8 Title Here</div>
      <div class="coolness-popup">this is placeholder text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>ode here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.coolness-popup` rule is not being marked as `position: absolute`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/a2egpyL0/1/ and [How to make div's percentage width relative to parent div and not viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867717/how-to-make-divs-percentage-width-relative-to-parent-div-and-not-viewport/13867800#13867800)

You'll still need to adjust top/left so they are correctly centered.

Comment: Yup! From [the MDN on top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top): 

"It has no effect on non-positioned elements."

Comment: Ah thanks.  I assumed that would be inherited, it never crossed my mind that it wouldn't be positioned.

Comment: Here's the page explaining that position is not inherited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#formal_definition