# CSS issues in Navigation for Safari osX

Tags: css, macos, cross-browser

The navigation looks perfect in every browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE9) but in Safari Mac it "Learning Center" in the navigation isn't stretching far enough.

It's like it's missing some padding or margin on all the menu items.

Here's the link for the site. http://previewyournewwebsite.info/otsl/about-us

Why doesn't it work in Safari and what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659359/100-width-divs-not-spanning-entire-width-of-the-browser-in-webkit

Answer (score 0):

In the body trying making it the full with and setting margin to 0:

```
html, body
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```